# Data not saving in MqSQL database which requests through a JSON request - Springboot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

When I run the code and send the **JSON** request, the requested data according to the **JSON** passes to the line, "**patientService.saveUser(user, patient, roleName);**" and I've already checked it with debug points but couldn't identify the problem. Also shows the message , "**Patient registration successful!**" as it is a success according to the **DefaultResponse** when I send the **JSON** request. But when I check the database through the workbench for the updated data, It shows the tables null. What is the problem with below codes and how to resolve it?

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/patient")
public class PatientController {

    private final PatientService patientService;

    @Autowired
    public PatientController(PatientService patientService) {
        this.patientService = patientService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public DefaultResponse savePatient(@RequestBody UserModel userModel) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(userModel.getEmail());
        user.setUsername(userModel.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(userModel.getPassword());
        Patient patient = new Patient();
        patient.setFirstName(userModel.getPatientModel().getFirstName());
        patient.setLastName(userModel.getPatientModel().getLastName());
        patient.setGender(userModel.getPatientModel().getGender());
        patient.setAge(userModel.getPatientModel().getAge());
        patient.setMobile(userModel.getPatientModel().getMobile());
        patient.setOrigin(userModel.getPatientModel().getOrigin());
        user.setRole(userModel.getRole());

        String roleName = userModel.getRole();

        try {
            patientService.saveUser(user, patient, roleName);
            return new DefaultResponse(200, "success", "Patient registration successful!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultResponse(400, "failed", "Patient registration unsuccessful!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class PatientService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PatientRepository patientRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PatientService(UserRepository userRepository, PatientRepository patientRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.patientRepository = patientRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void saveUser(User user, Patient patient, String roleName) {
        Role role = roleRepository.findByName(roleName);
        Set<Role> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
        userRoles.add(role);
        if (role != null) {
            userRepository.save(user);
            patient.setUser(user);
            patientRepository.save(patient);
        }
    }
}
```

**User Entity**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;
    private String role;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Patient patient;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name="users_roles",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="role_id")})
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    public User(String email, String username, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**Patient Entity**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Patient {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String gender;
    private String age;
    private String mobile;
    private String origin;
    

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    public Patient(String firstName, String lastName, String gender, String age, String mobile, String origin) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.age = age;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.origin = origin;

    }

}
```

**User DTO**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserModel {

    private String email;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private PatientModel patientModel;   
    private String role;

}
```

**Patient DTO**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PatientModel {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String gender;
    private String age;
    private String mobile;
    private String origin;
}
```

**Patient Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface PatientRepository extends JpaRepository<Patient, Long> {
}
```

**User Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

**Role Entity**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Role {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String name;

}
```

**Role Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
    Role findByName(String name);
}
```

**Properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/doc_pat_mgt?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

**JSON Request**

```
{
    "email": "dweerakoon71@gmail.com",
    "username": "dimantha1234",
    "password": "123456",
    
  "patientModel": {
    "firstName": "Dima",
    "lastName" : "Thira",
    "gender": "Male",
    "age": "27",
    "mobile": "0750650408",
    "origin" : "local"
  },
  "role": "PATIENT"
}
```

**After sending the request**

2023-09-29 19:22:59.171  INFO 19292 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

2023-09-29 19:22:59.172  INFO 19292 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'

2023-09-29 19:22:59.172  INFO 19292 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms

Hibernate: select role0_.id as id1_2_, role0_.name as name2_2_ from role role0_ where role0_.name=?